# Non-polynomial correlators for stochastic path integrals

Tags: path-integral, stochastic-processes, wick-theorem

What is the right way to evaluate a stochastic path-integral of the form:

$$\int \mathcal{D}x \mathcal{D}\tilde{x} \left( \int_0^T \sin(x(t_2)) x(t_2) dt_2 \int_0^T \tilde{x}(t_1)  dt_1 \right) e^{-\int \tilde{x}(t_1) G^{-1}(t_1,t_2) x(t_2) dt_1 dt_2}$$
Where $G^{-1} = \delta (t_2 - t_1) \frac{d}{dt_2}$ and $\tilde{x}(t) = i k(t) $ with $x(t), k(t)$ both real.

I think that if there were no $\sin(x(t))$ factor we could change the order of the path integral and regular integral, find the green function $G(t_1,t_2) = H(t_1 - t_2)$ and then apply wicks theorem.

$$ \int_0^T \langle x(t_1) \tilde{x}(t_2) \rangle dt_1 dt_2 = \int_0^T H(t_1 - t_2) dt_1 dt_2 $$
and so on for more correlators. And if instead of $\sin(x(t))$ we had some generic function of t

$$\int \mathcal{D}x \mathcal{D}\tilde{x} \int_0^T \left( g(t_1) x(t_1) \tilde{x}(t_2) \right) dt_1 dt_2 e^{-\int \tilde{x}(t) G^{-1}(t_1,t_2) x(t) dt_1 dt_2}$$
we would hopefully find
$$ \int_0^T \langle x(t_1) \tilde{x}(t_2) g(t_1) \rangle dt_1 dt_2 = \int_0^T g(t_1) H(t_1 - t_2) dt_1 dt_2 $$

My guess for how to deal with the $\sin(x(t))$ factor is to Taylor expand $\sin(x(t))$ in $x$ then apply wick's theorem, which I think would then produce zero for $\langle x(t_2) \tilde{x}(t_2) \sin(x(t_1) \rangle $ because powers of $x$ and $\tilde{x}$ would never match for any term in the expansion?